# Notation for the test of subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A,B$ be two sets.

Let's make a new notation $\cap^*$ such that $A\cap^* B=B$ if $B\subseteq A$, and $A\cap^* B=\emptyset$ if $B\not\subseteq A$.

Is this notation known? Are there any standard mathematical notation for $\cap^*$?

(This is very useful in coding.)

Comment: Which coding language?

Comment: @Alex I am looking for the mathematical notation not the coding notation, though. In most coding language I could just define a function.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use it?

Comment: @Alex One possible (but might not necessary) application is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3534172/the-largest-subset-of-x-is-also-an-element-of-another-power-set-c

Comment: The answer is below correct, but in that linked post, you would say $\cup_{c\subset A,c\in C}c$.  You would not need such a complicated function in order to state your question there.

Comment: @Alex Thx for saving my life ;)

Comment: I wish.  If there's something truly useful I can answer, let me know; I've been answer questions today almost without rep increase, so I can try helping some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical notation one uses branches in the definition of the function, like below

$$
A\cap^* B = \begin{cases}B,~\text{if}~B\subseteq A\\ \emptyset,~\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
which is pretty much what you've written already, but in a different layout.

Comment: Is this notation $\cap^*$ known somewhere or used in math literature?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous but I mean the notations similar to the one $\cap^*$ defined in the question. Is it used in literature?

Comment: I haven't seen your symbol before. Nor I know of another known symbol for the operation you define.